# WatchKit crash due to accepted event even if not everything is loaded

Tags: crash, mutex, watchkit

I have made an extension with a storyboard and some table view. In the simulator all is running ok, but when I try the app on Apple Watch I have some troubles. Since the Apple Watch is slower than the simulator it takes about one second to display the table views. During this time in the place of the table view is displayed nothing. If the user press the empty area that will be filled by the table view, as soon as the table view become visible it will be processed the event associated to the table view. I do not know why but this causes the app crash!!! I think everything would be solved if I do like in the other applications on my Apple Watch that while loading the view shows the rotating circle and not the elements of the view that are already in the storyboard (like buttons and labels) added at compile time. 
I have to say that maybe the crashed are due to an use of NSTimer that modify some variables modified by the app, maybe I should use a mutex. But I do not figure how in the Apple Watch the application crashes (or it appears the rotating circle and keep rotating) but in the simulator is ALL OK. What can I do? Do you need additional information? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code that are making crash your App?

Comment: It turned out that I was using multithreading in a bad way so I temporarily removed that code. In future I will have to use it so if I will have any further problem I may open another question. Thank you for the interest.